# Python - Ensuring a variable holds a positive number

Tags: python, variables, numbers

I am looking for an elegant way to ensure that a given variable remains positive.

I have two variables that hold positive float numbers and I decrement them according to certain conditions. At the end I want to guarantee that I still have positive numbers (or 0 at most). The pseudo code looks something like this:

```
list = [...]

value1 = N
value2 = M

for element in list:
    if ... :
        value1 -= X
    if ... :
        value2 -= Y
```

Is there a more elegant solution than just adding two `ifs` at the end?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am unclear as to what you want to do; numeric variables are either negative or not (never both).

- If you are decrementing a variable repeatedly and after doing so you want to check whether they are negative, do so with an `if` -- that's what it's for!

  ```
  if value < 0: # do stuff
  ```
- If you think the variables *should* never be negative and you want to assert this fact in the code in the code, you do

  ```
  assert value > 0
  ```

  which may raise an `AssertionError` if the condition doesn't hold (`assert` will only execute when Python is run in debug mode).
- If you want the variable to be 0 if it has been decreased below 0, do

  ```
  value = max(value, 0)
  ```
- If you want the variable to be negated if it is negative, do

  ```
  value = value if value > 0 else -value
  ```

  or

  ```
  value = abs(value)
  ```

Comment: I want the the variable to be 0, if decreased below zero, but thanks for the alternatives.

Answer (score 10):

Use `value1 = max(0, value1)` and the same for `value2` at the end of the iteration.

Answer (score 5):

For floats, I like the `max(0, value)` already given by Constantinius.  You can even combine it with the decrement and use tuple unpacking to handle both values at once:

```
value1, value2 = max(0, value1-1), max(0, value2-1)
```

Some tricks for integers only (for the record, since I already posted them without realizing you were dealing with floats):

When decrementing you can use this:

```
value -= value and 1
```

Assuming the value always starts out >= 0, this won't let it get below 0.

When the value is zero, this evaluates to `value -= 0`. When value is not zero, it evaluates to `value -= 1`.

You could also use the ternary operator, which is more readable:

```
value -= 1 if value > 0 else 0
```

Comment: `value` is a `float` not an `int`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on it: a class which acts as a soft limit to the numbers value:

The numbers will never be in an invalid state:

`SoftPositiveNumber(5) - 20 == 0` evaluates to true

```py
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class SoftPositiveNumber(object):
    """This class acts like a number but will not allow
    the contained value to be less than zero"""
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, SoftPositiveNumber):
            value = value.value
        self.value = value
        if self.value < 0:
            self.value = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value)
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"SoftPositiveNumber({self.value})"
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SoftPositiveNumber):
            return self.value == other.value
        return self.value == other
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SoftPositiveNumber):
            return self.value < other.value
        return self.value < other
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SoftPositiveNumber):
            self.value += other.value
        else:
            self.value += other
        if self.value < 0:
            self.value = 0
        return self
    def __isub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SoftPositiveNumber):
            self.value -= other.value
        else:
            self.value -= other
        if self.value < 0:
            self.value = 0
        return self
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SoftPositiveNumber):
            return SoftPositiveNumber(self.value + other.value)
        return SoftPositiveNumber(self.value + other)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, SoftPositiveNumber):
            return SoftPositiveNumber(self.value - other.value)
        return SoftPositiveNumber(self.value - other)
    __rsub__ = __sub__
    __radd__ = __add__
```

Comment: Seems clear to me the OP was looking for a solution based on "types," which classes can model. I doubt whether PEP 484 type hinting has enough to specify a type of positive numbers without some run-time support like this class, but I am not sure at all. In C, one might say "unsigned int" for integer types, but such would not work for floats. This solution looks good to me.