# Assign Positive Value to Variable

Tags: python

I need to ensure that f, a ,c, and p are all positive numbers so that the output is only positive.

```
import sympy

f,c,a,p,v = sympy.symbols('f c a p v')
expr = p*a*c*v**2 - 2*f

print(sympy.solve(expr, 'v'))
```

Comment: Use magic of `if`!

Comment: They aren't numbers, positive or negative; they're symbols. The result of `solve` is simply an expression solved for `v`.

Comment: Check it out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122535/python-ensuring-a-variable-holds-a-positive-number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Ensuring a variable holds a positive number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122535/python-ensuring-a-variable-holds-a-positive-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python's `map()` to apply a function (`abs()` in our case) to all variables in an iterable:

```
f, c, a, p,v = list(map(abs, sympy.symbols('f c a p v')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Equating provided variable to its absolute value could be sensitive.